# How to constraint already running interactive processes with cgroup2

Tags: linux, performance, systemd, cgroup

My home-server is running some aged hardware (Core i5-3450, software RAID1 on SATA disks) and often has problems when I run performance-intensive things like a compile-job besides "normal" services that run in the background (DNS, Web, DHCP, Mail, etc. etc.)

Recently I nearly trashed my system when a compile job got to nearly 100% CPU and in consequence the wait I/O skyrocketed as well and basically no other process could got any free resources anymore.

I read about cgroup2 and gave it a try. Set the grub option `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1` and rebooted. Created a new cgroup, activated I/O and CPU controller and was able to throw my compiler's PID into the cgroup.procs and was able to successfully put it into the "background" running with only 5% CPU and not interfering with the rest of the system. The compile job nearly took forever (several days), but I didn't mind. However multiple times per day, suddenly my cpu.max setting vanished and the system got out of equilibrium again. After reading more about cgroup and systemd I believe it's because I did meddle with systemd controls and basically systemd seemed to reset my custom settings back to the default (cpu.max == 'max 1000000') which then started trashing my system.

So I read about how to do it properly.

First I set `Delegate=true` to my `user@1000.service` file and rebooted.

Then I tried spawning a new "job" by running `systemd-run --user CPUQuota=5% stress-ng --matrix 0 -t 10m` which worked successfully, i.e. the CPU usage per process was limited to 5%/4 per stress-ng thread!

I can see a new directory below `/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service` which contains my setting:

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/run-raef937da699b484b80f1bf03bc049f7a.service/cpu.max
5000 100000
```

and `cgroups.procs` contains the corresponding PID of stress-ng. Success!

Now I might want to change that setting. Either because it's *too* low or for what other reason. May I just write another value directly to cpu.max? Or am I supposed to use a systemd command tool for doing that? (Which one?)

My other problem is: If I don't know beforehand that a command I am going to run might have a bad impact on my system performance-wise, how can I constraint it later-on without killing it and re-running using systemd-run?

Assume I just run "stress-ng" in my shell (without systemd-run), I can see it's PID being member of the normal session cgroup

```
cat /proc/742779/cgroup
0::/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-2232.scope
```

But **that** cgroup is managed by systemd, so I am not supposed (nor am I able to with normal user rights) to write into it's cpu.max, io.max, etc. structures, correct?

What ways of limiting do I have for already running processes running in the `session-xxx.scope` instead of under my `user@1000.service`? Can I "take ownership" of PID 742779 and transfer it somehow into my `user@1000.service` session?

I know there is cgcreate, cgclassify, etc. but those are cgroup1 only, correct? (At least they give me `cgcreate: libcgroup initialization failed: Cgroup is not mounted` as a result.)

Answer (score 0):

as already written elsewhere, `systemctl set-property`([manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#set-property%20UNIT%20PROPERTY=VALUE%E2%80%A6)) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks schtobia! Is there also a way to transition that particular PID I want to constraint to a completly different cgroup? `systemctl set-property` will affect always the whole cgroup with all the other PIDs in there, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure. `libcgroup` seems to be [cgroups v2 capable](https://github.com/libcgroup/libcgroup/issues/12), but I have no experience with it. And yes, `systemctl set-property` *will* always affect the whole cgroup - or, more correctly, the entire [unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).